# jquery, delete cookies from front end

Tags: session-cookies, logout, jquery-cookie

I want to use JQuery to delete cookies, when I click on log-out. I tried all and finally got this to work but, i want to make the path: / (root). But it just consider the page where i was at.

$.cookie('CookieName', null)

Also, can we be able to delete server side cookies from front-end. if not why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. $.cookie("name", null, { path: '/' });
2. Cookie is cookie, it doesn't matter where it was set, server-side cookies can be deleted from client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I did try this and then Path gets updated with page location url. But, as per the above mentioned answer, my path should be set to root itself.